# Clients can make maximum only 15 connections to ubuntu custom server

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, connection, mono

I have a custom server in C# being run on Ubuntu 9 under mono. I can make up to 15 silverlight clients connect to the server. When I make the 16th, it just waits. And if I close one of the established connections, the 16th client is able to connect. I am making the connections from one machine. I am also not exceeding any file handle limit. The limit is 1024 and I am having around 300.

Any ideas how to make more connections? Also why the number 15? Is it something linux-specific?

Comment: It seems likely that the problem is within your application, or mono.  Have you considered trying something like having more then 15 systems SSH or open some other long-lived connection into the Linux box?  Have you ruled out any restrictions by your ISP, or within your firweall?

Comment: @Zoredache I have tried with 20 SSH connections and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mono 2.6.7. Upgrading to 2.10.8 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem before - in that instance, a firewall had been setup on the server OS and it was throttling incoming connections to a maximum of 10 concurrent events.

Running `sudo iptables -L` and looking at the output (for text like '`limit`', or just `15`) might at least take such firewall throttling off the list of things to check. If there's a lot of output, then it's something to examine more closely as there will quite possibly be a system in place to generate a more complex set of rules. Adding such throttles can be quite common among such automated tools.

Comment: iptables -L produces the following:                            Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: so, it's not being used. It doesn't appear to be any firewall then from the local machine.